# yii2 assets missing when creating modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, yii2

I know there are a lot of similar questions I have tried all of them nothing working. In my modal there are assets missing, and I don't know how to, where to reload them.

EDIT: this is my start-form.php:

```
<?php $this->registerJsFile('js/voti.js'); ?>

    <div class="box-footer">
                    <center><button id="ladeauswertung" class="btn btn-default">Auswertung Laden</button></center>
                </div>

    <div id  ='auswertungdetail' name = 'auswertungdetail'>

    <?= $auswertungdetail ?>

    </div>
```

When the button "ladeauswertung" is clicked the followin JS code will be executed you can see here script-file.js:

```
$(document).on('click', '#ladeauswertung', function ()
{
    var ausgewaehlterstandort = document.getElementById("standorte").value;
    var datum = document.getElementById("datum").value;

    $.get("index.php?r=voti/ladeauswertung&standort=" + ausgewaehlterstandort + "&datum=" + datum,
            function (jsondata)
            {
                document.getElementById("auswertungdetail").innerHTML = jsondata;
            }
    );
});
```

and this code Part, which is in my controller:

```
$.get("index.php?r=voti/ladeauswertung&standort=" + ausgewaehlterstandort + "&datum=" + datum,
```

doing the following:

```
return $this->renderAjax('auswertungdetail', ["auswertung" => $auswertung, "gesamtauswertung" => $gesamtauswertung]);
```

so the modal appears after the button is clicked in my form, and in my modal there is a `daterangepicker` and a chart widget include. These widgets work great in every form BUT not in the modal, so I'm thinking that the assets are missing, but where do I load them?

Please help I'm searching since a couple of days.

Comment: what does the console shows you? are there any errors ?

Comment: no there aren't any errors, what i noticed is that a couple of assets are missing after i loaded my asset

Comment: so you are getting `404` for some assets in the console or how do you say that they are missing ?

Comment: i can check my website through my browser, and if im checking a form where the widgets work i can see the source files and there i see for example a datepicker.js. When im checking my modal there is the datepicker.js missing, so im thinking that i have to say somwhere that the modal includes the asset

Comment: add the modal code how you are loading the modal content

Comment: i have edit my main entry, you can see now that im generating my modal with the js-file and my controller

Comment: ??? hello no answer?

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML Code:

```
<div id  ='auswertungdetail' name = 'auswertungdetail'>
</div>
```

Your Javascript Code:

```
<script>
$(document).on('click', '#ladeauswertung', function ()
    {
        var ausgewaehlterstandort = document.getElementById("standorte").value;
        var datum = document.getElementById("datum").value;        
 $('#auswertungdetail').load("index.php?r=voti/ladeauswertung&standort="+ausgewaehlterstandort+"&datum="+datum").fadeIn("slow");
    }
    );

</script>
```

You just have to do coding in the controller as you are rendering the normal view.

Comment: **`Dirtiest`** Post ever you should read [**`THIS`**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: sorry i dont get it, my javascript code is in an extra file, and in my form its include with  $this->registerJsFile('js/voti.js');
and in this form im opening the modal -> this works.
but in the modal the widgets are not working in the form they working.
wo where do i have to post "your code" in the controller, form, or modal?